# Does any one know how to create dataframe in sparkR from hbase table?

Tags: sparkr

I am trying to create a spark dataframe in sparkR using data stored in hbase.

Does any one know how to specify the data source parameters in SQLontext or any other way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this package : http://spark-packages.org/package/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector.

However, it seems that you can't use it with SparkR yet and the two others packages providing connection between Spark and HBase don't seem to ba as advanced as the first one.

So I guess you won't be able to create a dataframe directly from HBase to SparkR.

Comment: As of yesterday Spark 1.4.1 is out and now you should be able to load Spark packages in SparkR.  I did not try it myself however.